# How to disable posting back entire page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm working on site in asp.net. the site present profile image in base64. When clicking on button or calling webmethod, the entire page posting page including the images and it is taking too long. there is a way to posting only what I need to post and refreshing the page? 
I do not want to use pageMethod, there is another way?

Comment: You tagged this as ASP Classic. I have removed the tag, as that is a completely different technology. Make sure you're only tagging the proper things.

Answer (score 2):

Either use Asp.net Ajax `<UpdatePanel>` tag in your asp.net page:

[Introduction to Asp.net Ajax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

or use jquery and json calls.